# 'TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Figure object' when creating a matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a beginner programmer in python and I'm trying to make an animation of a graph. I have written the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

datas = np.loadtxt('P5data.txt', skiprows=1)
x = datas[:, 0]
y = datas[:, 1]

def init():
    ax.set_ylim(min(y),max(y))
    ax.set_xlim(min(x),max(x))
    return line,

def update(frames):
    line.set_data(x[frames,:],y[frames,:])
    return line,

fig , ax = plt.figure()
line, = plt.plot([],[],lw=2)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func=init, frames=len(x), blit=True)

plt.show()
```

The program takes the data from a file with two columns and represents the second as a function of the first. When I run the program I get the error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Figure object
```

I see a window appear that I think is for the simulation, but it is empty. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with your animation. You are getting the error because `plt.figure()` creates a Figure object and you are trying to split that into two variables, `fig` and `ax` (in Python, this is called unpacking).

```py
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [2]: fig, ax = plt.figure()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[2], line 1
    fig, ax = plt.figure()

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Figure object
```

Replace that code with just

```py
fig = plt.figure()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I corrected what you suggest and I don't get the error. But the programm stil not working, it pops a white  window, where I think that should happen the simulation, and doesn't work. It says 'Figure 1 (No answer)'. After closing that window the kernel restarts automatically.

Also thanks for editing my post.

Comment: Does the window linger? Are you trying to plot line data or points? For a line, you should be slicing all points up to the frame number, i.e. `x[: frames]` (same for y).

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Figure object," is due to a small mistake in your code when you're creating the figure and axes. In Matplotlib, the plt.subplots() function is commonly used to create a figure and one or more axes objects. However, in your code, you've used plt.figure() which only creates a figure object and doesn't return the axes.

Comment: Tanks for the answer